# ASUS N550JV - Some programs don't display 1080p and contain blurry text after fresh Windows 8.1 Install

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, resolution

I recently installed Windows 8.1 on my [ASUS N500JV](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JV/). After the initial Windows updates (including Intel graphics HD 4600 driver), I installed the missing latest NVIDIA GT 750M driver.

Everything except some programs displayed just fine in HD 1080p; however, Google Chrome, some installation wizards and likewise programs displayed blurry text and was not on 1080p. What am I supposed to do in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making sure you get the latest drivers, do the following:

- Right click on desktop -> Screen Resolution
- Click on "Make text and other items smaller or larger"
- Check "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays"
- Choose Smaller - 100%

This should fix it.